# Error in Creating a product via xml in Amazon using Amzon MWS

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am getting an error every time I try to create a product in Amazon using XML and Amazon MWS Submit feed API.I have been trying this since 5 days but in vain. Please find below the link for create/list product xml and the result for the submission:

Create/list product feed:      http://pastebin.com/R2wf5mGs
Feed submission result: http://pastebin.com/RYc2wUXQ

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
    <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
      <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>MerchentId</MerchantIdentifier>
      </Header>
      <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
      <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
      <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Product>
          <SKU>DWKB8912</SKU>
          <StandardProductID>
            <Type>ASIN</Type>
            <Value>0141350679</Value>
          </StandardProductID>
          <Condition>
            <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
          </Condition>
          <NumberOfItems>1</NumberOfItems>
          <DescriptionData>
            <Title>Diary of a Wimpy Kid - Book 8: Hard Luck</Title>
            <Description>Howdy!!</Description>
            <MSRP currency="INR">205.00</MSRP>
            <IsGiftWrapAvailable>false</IsGiftWrapAvailable>
            <IsGiftMessageAvailable>false</IsGiftMessageAvailable>
            <RecommendedBrowseNode>1000</RecommendedBrowseNode>
          </DescriptionData>
          <ProductData>
            <Books>
              <ProductType>
                <BooksMisc>
                  <Author>Jeff Kinney</Author>
                  <Binding>Hardcover</Binding>
                  <PublicationDate>2014-01-31T11:03:11</PublicationDate>
                </BooksMisc>
              </ProductType>
            </Books>
          </ProductData>
        </Product>
      </Message>
    </AmazonEnvelope>
```

Comment: could you post some code?

Comment: c# code or the xml feed?

Answer (score 2):

Before doing anything else I checked whether your XML validates. Good start: it does. So any requirements that are actually part of the XSD are met. Unfortunately those are not the only requirements you'll have to meet, you may very well have a valid XML that is not accepted by Amazon for a number of reasons, so lets look at Amazon's response...

The processing response you put on Pastebin has an error message and two warnings:

- Error 8058: Some attributes are missing for SKU: [DWKB8912].For more details, see http://sellercentral.amazon.in/gp/errorcode/8058
- Warning 99041: A value was not provided for "brand_name". Please provide a value for "brand_name". This information appears on the product detail page and helps customers evaluate products.
- Warning 99041: A value was not provided for "bullet_point". Please provide a value for "bullet_point". This information appears on the product detail page and helps customers evaluate products.

Amazon's documentation on this is fairly crappy. The description of error 8058 says it should show the field name, which it clearly doesn't. It is unclear if getting rid of the two warnings will also get rid of the error, but nevertheless it is a start.

Please note that `brand_name` and `bullet_point` are the field names for the "flat file" CSV format. In XML, they're actually called `Brand` and `BulletPoint` and are part of the `DescriptionData` tag. (XML snippet follows)

```
<DescriptionData>
    <Title>Diary of a Wimpy Kid - Book 8: Hard Luck</Title>
    <Brand>INSERT BRAND NAME HERE</Brand>
    <Description>Howdy!!</Description>
    <BulletPoint>INSERT BULLET POINT HERE</BulletPoint>
    <BulletPoint>UP</BulletPoint>
    <BulletPoint>TO</BulletPoint>
    <BulletPoint>FIVE</BulletPoint>
    <BulletPoint>OF THESE</BulletPoint>
    <MSRP currency="INR">205.00</MSRP>
    <IsGiftWrapAvailable>false</IsGiftWrapAvailable>
    <IsGiftMessageAvailable>false</IsGiftMessageAvailable>
    <RecommendedBrowseNode>1000</RecommendedBrowseNode>
 </DescriptionData>
```

It is my recommendation to change your XML accordingly and see how that affects your processing report.

Comment: In sellercentral site I got the following error **Publication Year: The value for this field must be in the range 1,000 to 9,999 inclusive.** But the valid datetime xml accepts is of 2014-01-31T11:03:11 format.

Comment: @user2647674 You don't seem to be the only person with this problem:  https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=2582535 Is the error 8058 gone now?